# d3 js d3.stratify() how to handle a new column

Tags: javascript, d3.js

In order to color code the circle on my tidy tree chart I am using the scaleThreshold() function.
I have a first column with name (id) and a second column with values (sc).
Each name has one value.

If the value = 0 then the circle of that/those person on the chart will be grey
If the 1 < value < 3 then the circle of that/those person on the chart will be yellow
If the 4 < value < 10 then the circle of that/those person on the chart will be orange
If the 11 < value < 20 then the circle of that/those person on the chart will be yellow

I am struggling now to add that column "sc".

Is it in the stratify() function as .sc(function (d) {return d.sc}?

The circle will be colored then depending on that value

```
node.append("circle")
          .attr("r", 3.5)
           .style("fill", function(d) { return color(Sc.value) });
```

Any suggestion on how to preceed?
Thanks

```
<script>

    var color = d3.scaleThreshold()
        .domain([1, 4, 11])
        .range(["grey", "yellow", "orange", "Green"]);

    color(-1);   // "grey"
    color(0);    // "grey"
    color(1);    // "yellow"
    color(3);    // "yellow"
    color(4);    // "orange"
    color(10);   // "orange"
    color(11);   // "red"
    color(20);   // "red"
    color(1000); // "red"


    var svg = d3.select("svg"),
        width = +svg.attr("width"),
        height = +svg.attr("height"),
        g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(40,0)");

    var tree = d3.tree()
        .size([height, width - 160]);

    var stratify = d3.stratify()
          .parentId(function(d) { return d.id.substring(0, d.id.lastIndexOf(".")); });

    d3.csv("flare.csv", function(error, data) {
      if (error) throw error;

      var root = stratify(data)
          .sort(function(a, b) { return (a.height - b.height) || a.id.localeCompare(b.id); });

      var link = g.selectAll(".link")
        .data(tree(root).descendants().slice(1))
        .enter().append("path")
          .attr("class", "link")
          .attr("d", function(d) {
            return "M" + d.y + "," + d.x
                + "C" + (d.y + d.parent.y) / 2 + "," + d.x
                + " " + (d.y + d.parent.y) / 2 + "," + d.parent.x
                + " " + d.parent.y + "," + d.parent.x;
          });

      var node = g.selectAll(".node")
        .data(root.descendants())
        .enter().append("g")
          .attr("class", function(d) { return "node" + (d.children ? " node--internal" : " node--leaf"); })
          .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; })

    node.append("text")
          .attr("dy", 3)
          .attr("x", function(d) { return d.children ? -8 : 8; })
          .style("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.children ? "end" : "start"; })
          .text(function(d) { return d.id.substring(d.id.lastIndexOf(".") + 1); });

      node.append("circle")
          .attr("r", 3.5)
           .style("fill", function(d) { return color(Sc.value) });


    });

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `d.data.sc`:

```
node.append("circle")
    .attr("r", 3.5)
    .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.data.sc) });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Comment: But it doesn t seem to make a difference. I want that value to be the one in my second column (sc)

Comment: Do I have to define that value in the stratify() section?

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were copying Bostock's "flare.csv" verbatim. I edited the answer.

Comment: I am now wondering if it is possible to give the circle an internal color and a different external color. Any idea?

Comment: As this is another problem, please post another question.